# Xcode fails to Archive code, says ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 ARCHIVE FAILED

Tags: swift, xcode, archive

All I did was rename a method `addContentCapability` to `initialContentView`
On archiving I get the following error :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"_$s18PersonalFolderUxSdk0abC9ViewModelC010addContentE10CapabilityyyYaFTu", referenced from:
_$s20MyPersonalFolderUXSdk0aB11UxViewModelCN in MyPersonalFolderUxViewModel.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
** ARCHIVE FAILED **
```

I have tried to clean and rebuild
Cleared Derive Data
Rebuild the app
Re-attach the framework
Still facing the same issue

Expectation: Want the Xcode Archive to succeed